# Lua - Question on modules

Tags: module, lua

Say I want to make a module for say a set of GUI controls, how would I create a module that would load all of the GUI scripts, and should I put those scripts as modules themselves? I was thinking of having a system like this:

```
module("bgui", package.seeall)

dofile("modules/bgui/control.lua")
dofile("modules/bgui/container.lua")
dofile("modules/bgui/screenmanager.lua")
dofile("modules/bgui/form.lua")
dofile("modules/bgui/button.lua")
dofile("modules/bgui/textbox.lua")
dofile("modules/bgui/label.lua")
```

Would all the files run then have the variables they set as part of the bgui module?
Aka if in control.lua I had `control = {...}` would it be defined as bgui.control or should I make the control.lua a module itself, something like `module("bgui.control")` would that work as I intend?

Sorry if this isn't very clear had to write it in a rush, thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are actually asking two questions here:

#### First, "is this way of loading lots of files on a module ok?"

The answer is - **yes**. It is kind of an unspoken standard to call that file `mymodule/init.lua`. Most people have `?/init.lua` included on their `path`, so you can just write `require('modules/bgui')` and `init.lua` will be loaded automatically.

This said, you might want to remove some code duplication by using a temp table and a loop:

```lua
# modules/bgui/init.lua
local files = {
  'control', 'container', 'screenmanager', 'form', 'button', 'textbox', 'label'
}
for _,file in ipairs(files) do dofile("modules/bgui/" .. file .. ".lua") end
```

#### Second, "are objects defined on one file available on bgui?".

The answer is also **yes**, as long as the file defining the variable is "done" (with `dofile` or `require`) before the file using the variable.

Comment: Thanks so much, I couldn't seem to find much documentation on lua modules and this helps a tonne.